# How do I import multiple .py files to my main.py file

Tags: scripting, add-on, import

## I have a folder structure like this:

```
C: 
|_Blueprint
│   main.py
│
└───toolbox
        blueprint_tools.py
```

### When I run this code in Blender's scripting text page:

***from toolbox.blueprint_tools import dimension, array, modify***

### I get an error in the console

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\main.py", line 20, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'toolbox'
Error: Python script failed, check the message in the system console
```

---

I swear, when I run this code (on other projects) outside of Blender this structure and code runs fine. But I get an error when running this script in Blender for testing out my Add-On.

*If I compile the Blueprint folder into a .zip and install it everything works fine.... ??
I'm lost, could anyone please help me.*

### If I run the code like this: (added a . before toolbox for CWD)

***from .toolbox.blueprint_tools import dimension, array, modify***

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\main.py", line 20, in <module>
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
Error: Python script failed, check the message in the system console
```

Comment: `__init__.py` is missing for your module folder? [python - What is __init__.py for? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for)

Comment: I've tried... it doesn't work. When I hit run script I get --> ```ModuleNotFoundError: No module named toolbox.```

Comment: Why is it that everything works fine as is, if I install it.  But when I try to run script it crashes..?

Comment: Adding `__init__.py` doesn't help. I have the same issue

Comment: Blender built-in text/script editor is just for testing code snippets and not a good option for fully functional add-on development. Use vs-code for this purpose Answered here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/309332/add-on-dev-workflow-using-functions-and-modules https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YUytEtaVrrc

Comment: That's not true.  This seems like a personal opinion based on personal preference. Blender's text editor is fully suitable for writing text and that is all that is needed for developing any sort of add-on for Blender. It is definitely used to write add-ons. Is it worth considering a text editor that has more functionality for writing code? Sure, why not? But there is nothing wrong with using a basic text editor and Blender's internal text editor is fine for that and it also has syntax highlighting and you can just run any code you write in it without any additional setup.

Comment: And what solution do u suggest for the error: ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package?

Comment: You can see how any Blender add-on with multiple files works by simply having a look at their code.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64796854/how-to-make-a-blender-addon-with-multiple-folders) for example. But there is plenty of answers about that here on BSE already.