# Add-on Dev: Workflow using functions and modules?

Tags: python, add-on, development

First a small background story; I'm currently new into python development and I am teaching it myself on a hands on project. I'm developing an add-on in Blender 4.0 and sofar it goes all well (thanks to ChatGTP).

Now about the problem I have, where I could not find any good answer for. It's more of a workflow question.
I have an UI module, and each button in the UI is it's own module. Additionally I have a global functions module and this is where I'm facing some inconveniences.
I'm importing the functions in the beginning of my module, f.e. like this:

```
from .functions import get_last_node, check_selected_objs
```

And when I pack the add-on into a .zip file and install it in Blender, it works flawlessly. However it does not work if I run the module in the script editor. I get following error.

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

The way I'm working right now is; do changes in modules, remove add-on from blender, restart, repack .zip file with up to date files & install add-on again and see if my changes worked.
I doubt this is the best way, there must be a way to modify my modules inside Blenders Script Editor, no?

I appreciate any help on this topic and say thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to go back and forth with a .zip file. Just open the addon folder like `scripts\addons\my_addon` with a better editor like https://code.visualstudio.com/ and edit there.

Also try the extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JacquesLucke.blender-development It has a function to start Blender with the addon enabled, reloading and debugging.

Comment: Thank you that was exactly it. For people who might come across this in the future, here is a how to video on connecting VSCode with Blender:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YUytEtaVrrc